# How to remove role to access channel with discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I would like to avoid members to see a specific channel. 
I tried this but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I'm using discord.js v12 module.

```js
      const memberRole = await msg.guild.roles.cache.find((role: any) => role.name === "member")
      const permissionOverwrites = [{id: memberRole.id, deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']}];
      const channel = await msg.guild.channels.create(`channel`, { 
        type: "text", 
        permissionOverwrites,
        reason : "test",
      });
```

Iif I could remove the entire role from this channel it would be perfect.

thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using v11 code with the v12 module. In your case you would need:

```
let permissionOverwriteArray = [{id: memberRole.id, deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']}]


guild.channels.create('new-channel', { type: 'text', permissionOverwrites: permissionOverwriteArray, reason: 'New channel!' });
```

Comment: Hello, i can't see the difference with my code except you put rights into an object permissionOverwriteArray ?!

Comment: I updated my post and it still doesnt work

Comment: I have no error, evrything works fine but i can see member in the channel after the creation, i still have the same problem, i can't understand why

Comment: If you console log memberRole, what does it output?

Comment: Ok i just got it, it's because the channel is in a category and it inherit the category ! thx